# comprobar que una fila de una matriz (9x9) tiene los número del 1 al 9

Tags: c++

Este es mi código (es una función booleana que devuelve True si los ha encontrado todos), funciona pero me gustaría que fuera mucho más rápido

```
bool fila(const sud& s, int f) {
bool ok = true;
int aux = 1;
while (ok && aux < 10) {
    bool encon = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (!encon && i < N) {
        if (s[f][i] == aux) {
            encon = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (!encon) {
        ok = false;
    }
    aux++;
}
return ok;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un arreglo de `bool` en el que cada posición le corresponda a un número y sea `true` si lo encontró. Así no tienes que ir buscando los números individualmente.

Luego simplemente verificas que el arreglo tenga todos sus elementos en `true`.

```
bool fila(const sud& s, int f) {
    bool numerosEncontrados[10] = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        int numero = s[f][i];
        numerosEncontrados[numero] = true;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        if (!numerosEncontrados[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```